# Runtime Error on UVA judge and Wrong Answer on codechef on the samequestion

Tags: c, runtime-error

These are the links to the question on [codechef](https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&category=29&problem=1130&mosmsg=Submission+received+with+ID+15619115) and [UVa online Judge](http://www.codechef.com/problems/DPC103/)

My C code is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

char c;
int n,m;
char d;
int field=1;


    scanf("%d",&n);
    scanf("%c",&d);//reading space
    scanf("%d",&m);


while(1){

    int arr[n][m];
    if(n==0 || m==0)
     break;

    int i,j;

    scanf("%c",&d); //reading a return(\n)


for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    for(j=0;j<m;j++){
        scanf("%c",&c);
        if(c=='*'){
            arr[i][j]=-1;
        }
        else{
            arr[i][j]=0;
        }
    }       

        scanf("%c",&d); //reading a return(\n)  
}




for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    for(j=0;j<m;j++){
        if(arr[i][j]==-1){
            if(0<=i-1 && arr[i-1][j]!=-1){
                arr[i-1][j]++;
            }
            if(0<=j-1 && arr[i][j-1]!=-1){
                arr[i][j-1]++;
            }
            if(i+1<n && arr[i+1][j]!=-1 ){
                arr [i+1][j]++;
            }
            if(j+1<m && arr[i][j+1]!=-1){
                arr [i][j+1]++;
            }

            if(j+1<m && i-1>=0 && arr[i-1][j+1]!=-1){
                arr[i-1][j+1]++;
            }

            if(j+1<m && i+1<n && arr[i+1][j+1]!=-1){
                arr[i+1][j+1]++;
            }

            if(0<=j-1 && 0<=i-1 && arr[i-1][j-1]!=-1){
                arr[i-1][j-1]++;
            }
            if(0<=j-1 && i+1<=n && arr[i+1][j-1]!=-1){
                arr[i+1][j-1]++;
            }
        }   
    }
}

printf("Field #%d:\n",field++);
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    for(j=0;j<m;j++){
        if(arr[i][j]==-1)
                printf("*");
        else        
        printf("%d",arr[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}


    scanf("%d",&n);
    scanf("%c",&d);//reading a space
    scanf("%d",&m);

    if(n==0 || m==0) 
    break;


printf("\n");

}




return 0;
}
```

I get a runtime error on `UVA` and wrong Answer on `codechef`. What is the mistake?

Comment: Nope i don't .I have written all the if conditions.The code works on ideone.

Comment: https://ideone.com/bVutmB

Comment: This is ***not*** C++

Comment: You should also format and indent your code properly, this is atrocious

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to see where you have a runtime error?

Comment: No i did not do that.But i tried to run this on http://rextester.com/runcode. It does not work with gcc version of C but works with vc version of C.

Comment: Note: All your `scanf`s that ignores space and `\n` are not required as `%d` already skips them.

Comment: But that's not a problem

Comment: Take all your code, reformat it, and edit the question. I won't read that.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo here:

```
if(0<=j-1 && i+1<=n && arr[i+1][j-1]!=-1){
```

`i+1<=n` should be `i+1<n` just like you did for the other conditions.

Comment: UVa judge accepts it but it still fails on codechef